# Regex match Just Once (no repetition)

Tags: python, regex

I'm facing this little regex problem (flags: Global)

```
[-+*&|]
```

It is meant to match eg the + in this expression, but not the ++ or --:

```
12 + 47 - i++ / --foo
```

However it matches them all.

I know of this solution, but it's ugly (needs to repeat the group thrice):

```
[^-+*&|][-+*&|][^-+*&|]
```

Or perhaps

```
(?<![-+*&|])([-+*&|])(?![-+*&|])
```

Any nicer (shorter and more readable) solution?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I do NOT want to match the ++ and --.

Comment: @MightyPork Not even `+` in `++`?

Comment: Of course not, it's a different operator. I want just +'s and -'s that are on their own.

Comment: This is not a regular language. While you can match it with Python (or Perl, etc.) regexps, that doesn't mean you should; once you start using lookahead and lookbehind, you can easily get into exponential blowup. Also, your rule, no matter how pretty you make it, is going to fail to match `12+-3`, which I assume is perfectly valid in your language. So… why not use a simple OP parser instead of regexp?

Comment: can't reduce even more than this `(?<![-+*&|])([-+*&|])(?!\1)`

Comment: Yeah I think I'll try a different approach and just parse it char-by-char...

Comment: @AvinashRaj PCRE/perl `([-+*&\/])\1+(*SKIP)(*F)|(?1)`. I guess [it's still complicated](http://regex101.com/r/uZ5oX2/3). A simple loop should do the job.

Comment: You're trying to match operators only?

Comment: Yes, and whole operators, not parts of them. Either way I've got a different solution working, this question is now more academical.

Comment: If you're parsing it, why not split on space?

Comment: @Jerry No good, what if you get it without spaces?

Comment: Then what are the exact rules? What is possible and what will never be in the input? It's hard to give an expression without a solid pattern established.

Comment: @Jerry it's C-like syntax, which is quite obvious if you just look at it. If you intend to try to make a pattern, serve yourself, but it is no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

this seems a little more readable to me but not by much.

```
(?<![\+\-\*/\&\|])(?P<operator>[\+\-\*/\&\|])(?!(?P=operator))
```

matches:

```
+ ++ - -- * ** / // & && | ||
^    ^    ^    ^    ^    ^
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[-+*&|]{1,3}
```

you could use `{min,max}` for defining the min and max number of occurences.